# Get application from dll in compact framework 2.0

Tags: reflection, compact-framework, .net-2.0

I am trying to write a method for a Compact Framework 2.0 dll which will return the name of the parent application from which the dll is called but I am struggling to see how to do this.

Using reflection I am able to get the dll I have written etc - any ideas how to get the application name?

Thanks

Morris

Answer (score 0, accepted):

And if you want the full path to the EXE:

```
Assembly.GetCallingAssembly().GetName().CodeBase
```

Comment: Does it work if the exe is not calling directly the assembly, i.e. EXE -> DLL1 -> DLl2?

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```
AppDomain.CurrentDomain.FriendlyName
```